# Excel created by C# .net, not able to convert to pdf properly

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

I have an excel file stored in database.I am trying to export this file into pdf by using Aspose.Cell.

The pdf file which has been generated is not showing all the fields that exists in excel file.

```
byte[] data = GetInvoiceImageStream(invoiceId);
var fileName = codaOfficeCode.Trim() + "_" + 
               EfinanceStaticData.ManageAttachmentInvoiceCode + "_" + 
               invoiceNumber.Trim();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(ms);

workbook.Save("C:/xyz.pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf);
```

Comment: Not showing all the columns? Perhaps the paper size of the pdf needs to be bigger?

Comment: it is showing some data here and there, some row values from one column some from another column

Answer (score 1):

Please try these things.

Call **workbook.CalculateFormula()** before saving to pdf.

You can also create one page for entire worksheet. Please use **PdfSaveOptions.OnePagePerSheet** option and set it true.

```
PdfSaveOptions opts = new PdfSaveOptions();
opts.OnePagePerSheet = true;

workbook.Save("C:/xyz.pdf", opts);
```

If these things do not work, then please give a try to latest Aspose.Cells version and also post your issue in Aspose.Cells forum.

**Aspose.Cells Forum Link:**

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose